# Compare consecutive rows and delete based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare consecutive rows from the column `one` and delete based on this condition:

1. if 2 or more consecutive rows are the same, keep them
2. If one row it's different from the previous and the next delete it

Example df:

```
a = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'B', 'C'],['C', 'B', 'C'],['C', 'B', 'C'],['C', 'B', 'C']]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

print output would be:

```
one two three
0   A   B   C
1   A   B   C
2   B   B   C
3   D   B   C
4   C   B   C
5   C   B   C
```

Expected output would be:

```
   one  two three
    0   A   B   C
    1   A   B   C
    3   c   B   C
    4   C   B   C
    5   C   B   C
```

So the line from index 2 will be deleted.
I've tried using **shift** but I am a stucked, because like I am doing now, it deletes also the first and last column. Can someone please tell me a better way of doing this? Or maybe how to apply shift but ignore the first and last row ?

```
#First I take only the one column
df = df['one']
#Then apply shift
df.loc[df.shift(-1) == df]
```

With the above code I get this. Which is not correct because it delets also the first and last row

```
    0    A
    3    C
    4    C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try shifting up and down:

```
mask = (df.one == df.one.shift(-1)) | (df.one == df.one.shift(1))
adj_df = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use shift in both directions (and you need an `all` condition to check that all the columns are the same):

```
df[(df.shift(1) == df).all(axis=1) | (df.shift(-1) == df).all(axis=1)]
```